# How to get inline model in post_save instance (Django Signals)?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm using Django (1.11.7) and Signals for some actions on the newly saved model (sending a message to the mail with the info from the model, basically). But only I add to this model one more, connected (`ForeignKey`) with the main (as `inlines=[...]` in `admin.py`) — it does not participate in saving the instance of the main model.

My model is:

```
# /tours/models.py

class Tours(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(...)
    ...


class ToursHotels(models.Model):
    tour = models.ForeignKey(Tours, ...)
    cost = models.IntegerField(...)
    ...


@receiver(post_save, sender=Tours)
def do_something(sender, **kwargs):
    tour = Tours.objects.get(id=kwargs.get('instance').id)
    hotels = ToursHotels.objects.filter(tour_id=tour.id).order_by('cost')
    ...
```

So, `hotels` will be empty until I edit this record again.
How to do it better? Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the best practice is not to use `Django Signals` at all. Especially when there are built-in methods, such as [ModelAdmin.response_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_add), and leave from the model to `admin.py`:

```
# ./app/utils.py

def send_mail_to_admin(obj):
    hotels = obj.hotels.all().order_by('cost')

    message = 'Tour ID ' + obj.pk + '\n'
    message += 'Country: ' + obj.country_name + ' City: ' + obj.city_name + '\n'
    message += 'Hotels: \n'
    for hotel in hotels:
        message += hotel.name + ' ' + hotel.star + ' ' + hotel.cost + '\n'

    send_mail(
        'From Admin',
        message,
        'no-reply@example.com',
        ['admin@example.com'],
        fail_silently=False,
    )

# ./app/admin.py

from .utils import send_mail_to_admin


class ToursAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('created_at',)
    list_display = ('country_name',)
    ordering = ('created_at',)
    inlines = (HotelsInline,)

    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
        send_mail_to_admin(obj)
        return super().response_add(request, obj, post_url_continue)
```